# Does creating an empty table in MySql have any effect(downtime) on production?

Tags: mysql-5.5, amazon-rds

***Disclaimer: I am, in all probability, paranoid about pushing a patch on a production server.***

The patch alters the schema, by creating a new table (which is empty), and changes some stored procedures which do not run instantly when the patch is pushed. The altered stored procedure will not act upon already stored data but only new data that reaches the database.

**Does creating an empty table result in any significant amount of downtime or not?**

Comment: No, it does not.